# Where can I find good reference material for this domain_extractor?

Tags: php, regex

php.net has good reference material for [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and general [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).  I'm trying to understand this snippet I found on SO here:

I'm familiar with all of the snippet excecpt this bit:

```
?P<domain>
```

What does this part do in relation to the whole.  Particularly the '?P'.  I'm assuming the `<domain>` just defines a key in the associative array returned.

```
  function getDomain($url) 
    {
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if(preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) 
      {
      return $regs['domain'];
      }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?P<domain>` part defines the name of that group. That means that you can then access it by name with `$regs['domain']` instead of by number as `$regs[0]`. It's useful in large regexes since giving names to each of the groups makes it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: so ?P is part of that...is this referenced some where in php.net, I have links provided above.

Comment: In the documentation page for preg_match that you linked above, example 4 shows a named subpattern being used. They're also explained a bit here, although not specific to PHP: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html